# Graph DataGrid Data on Chart

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, mschart

I'm trying to convert my VB code to C# in way that I could plot a data values in datagridview on chart  ( or any easy way can do that using C#)

For example I created a code in fluid dynamic which calculate the water head diffusion from high potential to low potential with respect to X (distance)
using some linear analytical solution

As you can see my calculation was sent to the table under (hx column), 
then I plotted the hx data vs x values as it is shown in the figure:

[image]

This is the code which specifies the datagrid values

```
 Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.KeyPreview = True

    ' Dim dt As New DataTable()
    ' dt.Columns.Add("X_Value")
    ' dt.Columns.Add("Y_Value")
    uncGrid.DataSource = dt.DefaultView

    Chart1.DataSource = dt
    Chart1.Series(0).XValueMember = "Destance_at_Position(m)"
    Chart1.Series(0).YValueMembers = "hx(m)"
    Chart1.DataBind()

    Me.Chart1.Select()
End Sub
```

This is the lines where I bind the data with chart

```
Private Sub uncGrid_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles uncGrid.CellValidating
    If Me.Visible And Not uncGrid.DataSource Is Nothing Then
        Chart1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Finally this is for chart drawling and properties

```
Private Sub Chart1_PostPaint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPaintEventArgs) Handles Chart1.PostPaint
    Dim o As Object = e.ChartElement

    If o.[GetType]().Equals(GetType(System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series)) Then
        Dim xVal As Single = CSng(e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis(e.Chart.ChartAreas(0).Name, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisName.X, _x))
        Dim pt As PointF = e.ChartGraphics.GetAbsolutePoint(New PointF(xVal, 0))
        e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, pt, New PointF(pt.X, e.Chart.ClientSize.Height))

        If _x - 1 > -1 AndAlso _x - 1 < uncGrid.Rows.Count Then
            _dontDo = True
            uncGrid.ClearSelection()
            Me.uncGrid.Rows(_x - 1).Selected = True
            _dontDo = False
        End If
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the C# part where it shows many error and said undefined function

```
public Unconfined_Aquifer()
{
    Load += Unconfined_Aquifer_Load;
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyPreview = true;


    uncGrid.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;

    Chart1.DataSource = dt;
    Chart1.Series(0).XValueMember = "Destance_at_Position(m)";
    Chart1.Series(0).YValueMembers = "hx(m)";
    Chart1.DataBind();

    this.Chart1.Select();
}
```

Comment: OK, but what is the question? We don't translate here but we'll surely help when you run into trouble.. The C# code will be pretty much the same as in VB afaics..

Comment: I tried to implement the same on c# but didn't work

Comment: Show the code and specify the problems. 'didn't work' is not a valid problem description!

Comment: OK, Start by getting the syntax right: In c# the array indexer character is the square bracket not the parenthesis : `Chart1.Series[0]...` Also watch the spelling; by default controls start with lower-case letters.

Comment: what do you mean "by default controls start with lower-case letters."

Comment: Actually I'm a little unsure about this. VS names controls you drop onto your form starting with lowercase letters. Otoh VS17RC flag its own naming as wrong!?! (Maybe just a RC bug?) - Usually controls are lowercase (Camel case) and classes are uppercase (Pascal case). So Chart1 reads more like a Chart subclass than a control.

Comment: at first a wrote it "chart" and it gives error then I changed it uppercase" Chart" and it works. but still i'm not sure what is the problem

Comment: Not really a problem, but there are conventions laid down in style guides. Which VS version do you use?

Comment: I'm using  VS 2013 Ultimate